# 'Von etw ausgehen' in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've come across the following passage:

> Der Münchner Klub zum Beispiel gibt es seit 115 Jahren. Man ***geht*** hier
>   ***davon aus***, dass Esperanto auch in Zukunft weiterlebt und dass diese
>   internationale Sprache vielleicht sogar noch mehr an Bedeutung
>   gewinnt.

What does the term mean in this context? in dictionary the closest meaning is 'assume', but here it would be rather 'hope' or 'aspire', right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary is right, the meaning is *assume*. An assumption is something on which you base your actions. This is conveyed by *von etwas ausgehen*: This assumption is the starting point, you go from there. I assume that some members of the club justify their activities by the possible future importance of Esperanto.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it means me rather "**presume**" or "**take for granted**", as one assumes something without certain or factual evidences.

Comment: in this context, `expected` would fit as well imho ("One expects that Esperanto ..." or "One expects Esperanto to ...")